# Saying Tefillat haDerekh twice in one day

Tags: halacha, blessing, tefilat-haderech

The Tefillat haDerekh includes the phrase, "ותחזירנו לשלום" ("and may you return us in peace"), to be added in the event that a person plans to make a return journey the same day. Is it necessary to add this, or is it permissible to recite Tefillat haDerekh again on the way home instead? Assuming that the latter option is permissible, would it not be preferable? Instead of adding a line to a berakhah, one gets to make a whole new berakhah instead!

Comment: Extra Brachot are generally avoided. (Eg. you wouldn't say Borei Nefashot and then Shehakol between each gulp of orange juice, right?)

Comment: Note many Rishonim did not have the "ותחזירנו לשלום" option in their texts, so even omitting it probably wouldn't obligate you to say it again, if you already intended to return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrariwise. If you plan on making a round-trip journey in one day, you should add in the line and only say the prayer once. We avoid saying unnecessary blessings. (*Bracha she'eina tzricha.*) Just as if you're handed a piece of meat and a glass of water, you should say shehakol on the meat and have in mind to include the water, rather than say two separate shehakols. That's not considered respectful use of God's name.

A person would say it twice in one day if their plans changed, and they found themselves making another journey (or a return trip) on the same day that they hadn't intended when first making the blessing.